# Create list/array of Textviews to change .text via index

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

So I was hoping to make a list/array of textviews so that I can iterate a loop and set the .text value of the TextViews as I go. Otherwise I would have to set the values in the code statically which would be a whole lot messier and potentially not even feasible for my needs.

So in the code below the idea would be to iterate the loop and when the correct value is confirmed that [index] would then set the corresponding

```
var refillToken : Double = (0).toDouble()
var tweetStored : BooleanArray = BooleanArray(20)
var tweetActive : BooleanArray = BooleanArray(20)
var userID: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf("")
var textViewToken = 0

while (refillToken > 0) {
                var token: Int = 0
                while (token < (tweetStored.size)) {
                    if (tweetStored[token] == true) {
                        tweetActive[token] = true
                        textView[textViewToken].text = userID[token]
                        textViewToken++
                        refillToken--
                        token++
                        if (refillToken < 0) {
                            break
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I know my loop is probably messy by sane people standards but it makes sense to me and (hopefully) isn't the issue at play. Have found a few articles or ideas searching for the past two hours but they're either 10 years old (and I think deprecated), for java or don't work for whatever reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get a value and then add it to the textview and change this value after every action on the page.
Use variable assignment for this task

Comment: So sorry man but I'm really not sure what you mean by this. Are you saying I need to add another attribute to the textview in the layout file so that it can keep track of actions in the activity?

Comment: You define a global variable, give the value to the variable in the function, and then add it to the text view